# Separators between elements without hacks

Tags: html, css

One thing I often want to do when laying out a website is to have some elements next to each other, with separators between them. For instance, if I have three elements, I'd want two separators between them, and nothing at either end.

I achieve this in various ways. For vertical stacking of elements, I sometimes use `<hr />`. Horizontally, I might do something like:

```
<div>
    <span class="notend">things</span>
    <span class="notend">stuff</span>
    <span>items</span>
</div>

.notend {
    border-right: solid black 1px;
}
```

Is there a more semantic way of doing this? I want to have separators between elements without putting styling elements into the HTML part, or using non-semantic classes. I don't mind of this requires hacky CSS, I just want to get stuff to do with styling away from the HTML files.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use this:

```
#menu span + span {
    border-left: solid black 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QxZ6D/

That will apply `border-left` to all except the first `span`.

The [adjacent sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector) (`+`) is supported in all modern browsers except IE6.

---

Another way to do it is this, which is sometimes nicer because you can keep all the declarations for the "menu buttons" in one block:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QxZ6D/1/

```
#menu span {
    border-left: solid black 1px;
    /*
    a: bunch;
    of: stuff;
    */
}
#menu span:first-child {
    border-left: 0
}
```

This has exactly the same level of browser support as the first solution.

Note that if you like this solution, it's better to use `:first-child` rather than `:last-child`, because `:first-child` (from CSS2) is supported in IE7/8 and `:last-child` (only introduced in CSS3!) isn't.

Comment: Nice! I wish I'd found that before.

Comment: It surprises me how little-known the `+` selector is. Look at all the `:last-child` answers here and elsewhere on the site...

Comment: IE6 doesn't support something that every other browser in the world does!?  I'm so disillusioned...

Comment: "in all modern browsers except IE6" - why am I implying that IE6 is a modern browser?

Answer (score 9):

you can do like this also:

```
span {position:relative; margin-left:5px}

span:after {
    content:"|";
    position:absolute;
    left:-5px;
}
span:first-child:after {
    content:"";
}
```

In this method you can also use others separators like `/` , `\` , `.`

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/UNnxE/

Answer (score 4):

how about something like this in your example:

```
<div>
    <span>things</span>
    <span>stuff</span>
    <span>items</span>
</div>

div span{
   border-left: solid black 1px;
}
div span:last-child{
   border:none;
}
```

no need for additional classes.

Answer (score 4):

I often want to have a series of items with semi-colons between them.

Here's what I do for this:

```
.semi-list span:not(:last-of-type)::after {
  content: "; ";
 }

<div class="semi-list">
  <span>Item One</span>
  <span>Item Two</span>
  <span>Item Three</span>
</div>
```

It's a pretty flexible solution.

Ref:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_last-of-type.asp

Answer (score 2):

Well for a start, you can simplify it to this:

```html
<div>
    <span>things</span>
    <span>stuff</span>
    <span class="end">items</span>
</div>
```

```css
span {
    border-right: solid black 1px;
}
span.end {
    border-right: none;
}
```

---

If you're willing to drop some support in older browsers, you can reduce that to this, using the [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo-class:

```html
<div>
    <span>things</span>
    <span>stuff</span>
    <span>items</span>
</div>
```

```css
span {
    border-right: solid black 1px;
}
span:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Comment: @Oliver, And in order to achieve "element1 | element2 | element3" you'd probably want to do border-right instead of border-left.  Or make the special case class the first element and not the last.

Comment: Yeah, I notice that now. I tend to get left & right mixed up (very inconvinient when trying to navigate).

Comment: @MikeC: Good point! I would have spotted that if I'd actually read the code I was writing.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

CSS:

```
#note_list span {
    display:inline-block;
     padding:0 10px;
}
.notend {
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="note_list">
  <span class="notend">things</span>
  <span class="notend">stuff</span>
  <span>items</span>
</div>
```