# Formatting divs through css

Tags: css, formatting

I have the following structure

```
<div class="mainmenu">
    <div>
      Home
    </div>
    <div>
      About us
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem
    </div>
</div>

.mainmenu div
{
     border-right:1px #000 solid;
}
```

With this I can enable the right border for all divs, but I don't want border in the last div. Is it possible to control this through css, without modifying the structure above?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729566/separators-between-elements-without-hacks/7729610#7729610

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes (with pseudo selectors):

```
.mainmenu div:last-child
{
     border-right:none;
}
```

Note: supported only in browsers that support css3.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 now lets us select a certain 'child' and apply styling like so:

```
.mainmenu div:last-child{
 border: none;   
}
```

However CSS3 is not a safe path to go down yet for older browsers so another option would be to give your last div the class of 'last' and styling it like so:

```
<div class="last">
  Lorem
</div>

.mainmenu .last{
 border: none;   
}
```

You can have multiple classes in a div so you can apply the 'last' option as well as whatever else the div is called e.g.

```
<div class="apple last">
  Lorem
</div>
```

Comment: Ya, it was more of an addition to let him know that it might not work in older browsers, but, yep, I should have specified that.