# Add space between HTML elements only using CSS

Tags: css, layout, receipt

I have several same HTML elements going one after another:

```
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
```

I'm looking for the best way of adding space *between* the elements using **CSS only**

```
[no space]  [1]  [space 10px]  [2]  [space 10px]  [3]  [no space]
```

Additionally:

- Please write down browser compatibility of your receipts

---

I don't want to use *any additional HTML markup* like

```
<span></span>  <span></span>  <span class="last_span"></span>
```

I don't want to use tables.

I want the first and last span to be targeted automatically by CSS.

I don't want to use JavaScript.

> ***Optional requirement***: last span can be *not last child* of the parent tag, but it will be the *last span* of the parent tag. Spans do
> not have any other tags between them.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a table. Depends on what data goes into the `text`

Comment: Is the number of `span`s variable?

Comment: @Truth last resort should be tables.

Comment: The `span` elements are generated by the web service I don't have access to. So I can't change the markup. However, I can fully use CSS

Comment: With questions like this, you should always specify the browser support you require. "I need IE7 support" will receive completely different answers to "I'm only using Chrome".

Comment: @TimJoyce not if the data he's inputting is tablar, in which case it's the first resort.

Comment: @thirtydot I didn't know it was ever possible in IE6, IE7

Answer (score 356, accepted):

A good way to do it is this:

```
span + span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Every `span` preceded by a `span` (so, every `span` except the first) will have `margin-left: 10px`.

Here's a more detailed answer to a similar question: [Separators between elements without hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729566/separators-between-elements-without-hacks/7729610#7729610)

Comment: This is a nice solution, though if your container will span to multiple lines it fails.

Comment: It also works with classes, like this: `.sidebar-img + .sidebar-text  { margin-left: 40px; }`

Comment: How do you handle when the items wrap to the next line?

Comment: @thdoan: It depends on your layout, etc. You can try something like [this](https://jaketrent.com/post/spacing-between-multiline-flexbox-child-elements/#multi-line-for-flex-wrap-ed-designs).

Comment: I prefer reddtoric's solution using grid and grid-gap.

Answer (score 47):

Add these rules to the parent container:

```
display: grid
grid-auto-flow: column
grid-column-gap: 10px
```

A good reference: *[CSS Reference - A free visual guide to CSS](https://cssreference.io/)*

Browser compatibility: *[Browser Support for CSS Grid Layout](https://gridbyexample.com/browsers/)*

Comment: `grid-auto-columns="max-content"` may also be useful. It will make the grid item's size match the content. Also, browser compatibility shouldn't be an issue anymore: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I know comments are not for thanks, i was only making use of the 'flex' display until now, and this 'grid' thing makes it all so easy from the parent container itself! To not leave it entirely useless, would add the following reference that helps a lot for anyone looking to learn more:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 45):

Just use margin or padding.

In your specific case, you could use `margin:0 10px` only on the second `<span>`.

Here's a nice CSS 3 solution ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Simo990/dTmy6/1/)):

```
span {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

span:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0;
}

span:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Advanced element selection using selectors like `:nth-child()`, `:last-child`, `:first-of-type`, etc. is supported since [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9).

Comment: You have a great answer, Simone, but could you please solve the question without specifying the last `span` manually? This should be the CSS's job

Comment: this is an unneded hack, that's the "word-spacing" property for: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp check Ben's answer

Comment: the OP wanted space between spans, so it's ok to give a solution for inline elements, the margin/padding/first/last properties are not needed here and only adds complexity

Comment: Actually, the OP said he'll be using `span`s and `div`s (which are block elements). Your solution is valid anyway if you define `div`s as inline elements...

Answer (score 23):

You can style elements with excluding the first one, just in one line of code:

```
span ~ span {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

There isn't a need to change any classes.

Comment: This one works perfekt. span + span didnt work but span ~ span works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: In my case, I have several spans, some of which may not contain the class "Showing", so what I need is `span.Showing ~ span.Showing` instead of `span.Showing + span.Showing`. `~` is the general sibling selector, where one doesn't need to directly follow another.

Answer (score 12):

You can take advantage of the fact that `span` is an inline element:

```
span{
     word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

However, this solution will break if you have more than one word of text in your span.

Answer (score 9):

```
span:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to align various items and you like to have the same margin around all sides, you can use the following. Each element within `container`, regardless of type, will receive the same surrounding margin.

[image]

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > * {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

If you wish to align items in a row, but have the first element touch the leftmost edge of `container`, and have all other elements be equally spaced, you can use this:

[image]

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container > :first-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.container > *:not(:first-child) {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

You can write like this:

```
span{
    margin-left: 10px;
}

span:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap your elements inside a container, use new CSS 3 features like [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/), [a free course](https://cssgrid.io/), and then use `grid-gap:value` that was created for your specific problem.

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.inRow{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px /* This adds space between elements, only works on grid items */
}
.inColumn{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inrow">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="inColumn">
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I was looking to add space between elements of a div class using css style. I used your example to build my code for that. Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the course!

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` is an inline element, so you can’t make spacing on them without making it block level.

Try this:

Horizontal

```
span{
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Vertical

```
span{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

It is compatible with all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Or, instead of setting margin and then overriding it, you can just set it properly right away with the following combination:

```
span:not(:first-of-type) {
    margin-left:  5px;
}

span:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, the restriction is the browser support of `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` CSS selectors.

Comment: ...also check for `not` expression browser support

Comment: @Dan [it's](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) actually great, all several last-years browsers are covered. But I must admit, that yzoja's solution is even smarter :)

Comment: This solution is superior in the specific case that you are going to also include borders between elements as separators (so like a UL in a nav, for example), as it will properly place the border in the middle of the spacing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
span.middle {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px; /* top right bottom left */
}
```

```html
<span>text</span> <span class="middle">text</span> <span>text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Horizontal space */
.space-8-x > * + * {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
/* Vertical space */
.space-8-y > * + * {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```
<div class="space-8-x">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>

<div class="space-8-y">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```