# Put space between lists

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I have two lists that I want to be grouped together, but I would them to have some space between them, something like one or two whitespaces. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/h7gxpqn0/16/). I've tried several solutions found on questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184958/add-space-between-html-elements-only-using-css), but none of them actually worked.

Here is my CSS:

```
ol {
    display: inline-block;
}
ol.ui-listview>li>.ui-btn:first-child:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-li-static:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>label:before, ol.ui-listview>li.ui-field-contain>.ui-controlgroup-label:before{
    content: counter(listnumbering) !important;
}

#slots {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: You arn't looking for something like ol{margin-right:20px;} ?

Comment: @kurt that's it! Add `!important` as a keyword and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `margin-right` to add space between the two `ol` elements as they are displayed as inline block elements.

However a generic `ol` selector would not help as other CSS rules from libraries are overwriting it and so you can use the below selector which is more specific and hence wouldn't be overwritten.

```
.ui-block-a ol[data-role="listview"]{
    margin-right: 16px; 
}
```

**Note:** Adding an `!important` keyword is generally a bad practice and should be avoided wherever possible. Here it is not needed as the selector is more specific.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h7gxpqn0/17/) (snippet seems to lose the styling)

Comment: What do you mean snippet seems to lose the styling? Actually I do not know what is a snippet. I mean your solution is fine! :)

Comment: @gsamaras: In SO there is a stack snippet option to add runnable HTML/CSS/JS code by clicking on the `<>` icon from toolbar. That generally allows for all external libraries also to be included but doesn't seem to work here for some reason. The fiddle works perfectly as intended :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a margin-right css property...

```css
ol{
  margin-right:20px !important;
  }
```

Comment: Kurt I accepted Harry's answer because it's more specific to jQuery mobile, but of course you deserve a +1.