# Separator between visible elements

Tags: html, css, border

I have a similar problem like [Separators between elements without hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7729566/282601), but do not want to show the separator if the element on the left left or right is invisible.

The elements:

```
<a>1</a> <a>2</a> <a>3</a> <a>4</a>
```

together with the CSS:

```
a + a {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

get rendered nicely:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

As soon as 1 or 4 become invisible with `display:none`

```
<a style="display:none">1</a> <a>2</a> <a>3</a> <a style="display:none">4</a>
```

there is a problem:

```
| 2 | 3 |
```

How do I get rid of the border to the invisible elements?

Comment: On first sight I don't think you can. For CSS, there still is an anchor after an anchor. I don't think you can fix this without JS.

Comment: would something like `a:after {content:(""); border-left:1px solid black}` do the job?

Comment: oops, my syntax there is dodgy; see below for a full answer

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on my comment to your question, a pseudo-element seems to do the job.

**HTML:**

```
<a>1</a> <a style="display:none">2</a> <a>3</a> <a>4</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a+a:before {
    content:"";
    border-right:solid 1px black;
}
```

gives you:

`1 | 3 | 4`

http://jsfiddle.net/hv7HX/1/

Essentially, since the border is attached to the element itself using :after, it disappears when the element disappears.

Comment: Watch out, CSS generated content [is troublesome or missing before IE9](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).

Comment: True, it's a careful judgement call when pseudo elements really.

Comment: This does work when 2, 3 and 4 become invisible. It does not work when 1 becomes invisible - the border from 2 is then still there.

Comment: Ah, good point. It might be time to address with js/query, if it's really this crucial. You could use a visible selector, perhaps, to apply an appropriate class, e.g http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/